# Overly strict typing in Z3 Java API?

Tags: java, z3

In the Java API for z3, addition and other similar operators can only be done with `ArithExpr`s:

```
ArithExpr x = ctx.mkInt(0);
ArithExpr y = ctx.mkInt(1);
// Compiles:
ctx.mkAdd(x, y);
// Does not compile:
ctx.mkAdd((Expr) x, (Expr) y);
```

But `ArithExpr` as a Java class does not contain all possible expressions. For example, `mkITE` returns an `Expr`, but even if the result of the if-then-else is an integer, the Java API will not allow operations on it because it's not the right Java class. (This is the problem I'm running in to in my code.)

Am I missing something, or is this a (perhaps unintended) limitation of the Java API?

Comment: You should be able to cast the result of ctx.mkITE into (ArithExpr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a limitation, it's a fully intended design choice. Some functions can return arbitrary Expr's, some are more specialized and only return an ArithExpr (which derives from Expr), some are even further specialized and return an IntExpr. If we know what to expect from functions like `mkITE` (as in your example) then we can cast the output to the desired type, and that is the preferred paradigm.

Internally, ever Expr that comes out of Z3 is checked in the API (`Expr.create`), so Java knows the type hierarchy of every Expr and what they can be cast to.